# Plugin does not exist or no valid version can be found error

Tags: maven-2, hudson, jira, hudson-plugins

I have downloaded the complete source of hudson jira API plugins and am trying to build it by mvn install. The jira plugin gets build properly, but when it tries to build the hudson plugin, I am getting the error

[INFO] The plugin 'org.kohsuke:access-modifier-checker' does not exist or no valid version could be found. The access-modifier-checker jar file (1.0) is present in my local repository.

Tried this from multiple machines and I am getting the same error. Also I tried to google the issue, but to no avail. Is there anything I am missing?

edit: I have also tried deleting the contents of .m2/repository folder

edit2: pom.xml snippet

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kohsuke</groupId>
        <artifactId>access-modifier-checker</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: which version does the Hudson plugin depend on? Check the pom.xml, it might depend on an older version.

Comment: did you find out how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The JIRA plugin jar file needs to be installed in {jira.home}/plugins/installed-plugins for version 2 plugins, or atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/lib for version 1 plugins.

Comment: Thanks Matt, but what I am trying to do here is build the hudson plugin.